# Getting context path without depending on servlets in spring

Tags: spring, url, web

I am getting context path by using below code.

```
String  contextpath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("sample.html");
```

But as my code is in business side, I use only method here to pass the `file name` , according to file name I need to get path of that war folder in server how could I get it?

I am using spring web application.

Comment: You can write ServletListener and set some static value in application

Comment: @Sangram Jadhav can you show me in code.

Comment: [Getting The Context Path (Without a HttpRequest)](http://jblewitt.com/blog/?p=365)

Comment: @Sangram Jadhav  ServletContextInfo in this property file which getters and setters i need to put.Please help me on this i am new bie to java

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a88ebb3b142cefadd951fb469c6fb85c

Comment: @Sangram Jadhav In ServletContextInfo.java file for ROOT_PATH it says syntax error on token "ROOT_PATH",variableDeclaratorId expected after this token.What should i do for this?.If i make it as string error goes but it is not returning anything.

Comment: replace that line with `private static String ROOT_PATH = null;`

Comment: @Sangram Jadhav I have used private static String ROOT_PATH = null; but its returning blank,nothing it is returning.

Comment: @Sangram Jadhav Your answer worked by changing getContextPath() to getRealPath().If you put that answer here i get mark right and other can get to know answer.Thank you once again.You are my charm:)

Comment: My pleasure. I'll add the link as an answer. All credit belongs to author of that page

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We need Real path in service/dao/resource layer for doing many things. It is good idea to extract that path when a web application is initialized and store it somewhere where all layers of system can access it.

A way to do this is through ServletListener interface. Below is the link which exactly shows how to do it.

[Getting The Context Path (Without a HttpRequest)](http://jblewitt.com/blog/?p=365)

Comment: Your propoposed solution still requires the ServletContext :-/

Answer (score 0):

For a Spring application, you can just use an application context aware bean. As the application is a web application, the ApplicationContext will be a `WebApplicationContext`, so you can ask it for the ServletContext:

```
public class ContextPathHolder
        implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private String contextPath;
    private String realPath;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) {
        wac = (WebApplicationContext) ac;
    }

    public void     afterPropertiesSet() {
        ServletContext sc = wac.getServletContext();
        contextPath = sc.getContextPath();
        realPath = sc.getRealPath();
    }

    public String getContextPath() {
        return contextPath;
    }

    public String getRealPath() {
        return realPath;
    }
}
```

That way, you have a simple bean that you can inject in any other bean that would need the servlet context path.

---

Usage example assuming xml configuration:

Service class requiring access to real context path:

```
class ConfigurableServiceImpl implements ConfigurableService {

    private ContextPathHolder pathHolder;
    public setPathHolder(ContextPathHolder pathHolder) {
        this.pathHolder = pathHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public MyServiceObject myServiceMethod(...) {
        String realContextPath = pathHolder.getRealPath(); // get the real path...
    ...
}
```

Spring XML root context

```
<bean id="contextWebApplicationContextProvider" class="...ResourcePathHolder"/>
<bean id="configurableService" class="...ConfigurableServiceImpl"
        p:pathHolder="contextWebApplicationContextProvider">
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: How to call realPath in method of some other class

Comment: in applicationcontext.xml i have used <bean id="contextWebApplicationContextProvider" class="com.dev.events.ResourcePathHolder"></bean> and I used String contextPath = ApplicatContxt.afterPropertiesSet().realPath; in one of method of class but i wont get any intilej after ApplicatContxt and shows error.Could you please explain what or how should be done?